# D3: re-assigning link = link.data(...): why? how?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to figure out one detail of the `.data()` method.  Can someone shed some light on this?

In mbostok's examples, for example in [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795) (excerpted below), notice that `link` is initially assigned to the results of `svg.selectAll()`.  Later, in the `start(`) method, `link` is (repeatedly) reassigned to the results of `link.data()`.  (Note: this is true of the `node` variable as well, but I'm just focusing on one for simplicity.)

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link");
...

function start() {
  link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
  link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
  link.exit().remove();
  ...
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
  ...
}
```

I would have expected the code to be written:

```
var link;
...
function start() {
  link = svg.selectAll(".link").data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
  ...
}
function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
  ...
}
```

I've confirmed that this works, but I'm sure mbostok had a reason for doing it the other way -- I'm guessing because it's more efficient than calling `selectAll()` each time.  But what is the output of `.data()` that allows for reassigning `link` repeatedly?  Is the result of `data()` itself a selection?

In other words, what's going on here?

Comment: The [documentation says it pretty clearly](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data): `The result of the data method is the update selection; this represents the selected DOM elements that were successfully bound to the specified data elements.`

Comment: I must have read over that very documentation a dozen times, but this time it makes more sense: `data()` return a selection (i.e. similar to what `svg.selectAll(".link")` returns), except it is also decorated with custom `.enter()` and `.exit()` methods.  Is that a reasonable way of thinking about it?

Comment: Yes.  `.selectAll` returns a regular selection.  `.data`, though, returns the **update selection** which is special because now it's data-bound and knows what's updating, entering and exiting. From the [thinking with joins](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) article: `The update selection is returned by selection.data, while the enter and exit selections hang off the update selection...`

Comment: @mark: wanna checkmark?